# Installed Raspbian and can't backup with Timeshift

Tags: backup, resize

I haven't seen this issue posted anywhere else. It's not the same issue.
Basically, I'm installing Raspbian with a fresh install. I boot into it and am immediately low on disk space.
Here's why:

```
df -h
Filesystem    Size  Used  Avail  Use%  Mounted on
/dev/root     15G   3.3G  11G    24%   /
..... a bunch of other tiny partitions
/dev/mmcblk0p1 44M  4.0k  44M    1%    /boot
```

I can install applications just fine. But I can't create a backup with Timeshift. It's trying to back up to my /boot partition and not my root partition. Why?

Comment: How is the disk space low? You appear to have 76% (11G of 15G) available

Comment: And it looks like you have 99% of /boot available. I think your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Tell timeshift not to backup to /boot. Not a Pi problem.

Comment: I can't select that partition. Timeshift just shows my smaller partition.

Comment: I guess its looking for another drive and thinks the FAT vs EXT formatted partitions are two physical drives.  Seen this under Ubuntu where you could only back up to the USB stick (FAT32) no matter how the internal drive was partitioned if they where all EXT 'drives'.

Comment: Oh boy. That stinks.

Comment: I use raspibackup for my Pi backups https://github.com/framps/raspiBackup

Comment: You obviously aren't installing the latest Raspberry Pi OS

Comment: You use an old Raspbian image with a **FAT** boot partition of only 44 MB. You should flash an up to date [Raspberry Pi OS](https://www.raspberrypi.org/software/operating-systems/) with a boot partition of 253 MB.

Comment: Oh weird. I'll try that. I used NOOBS as my bootstrapper. It was a fresh install, but maybe the newest version of Raspberry Pi wasn't in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the man page suggests, try adding `--snapshot-device /dev/root`, or set `backup_device_uuid` in `/etc/timeshift.json` to configure it for your system.

Side note: `/dev/root` is a rather odd name, your root filesystem should be on `/dev/mmcblk0p2` on an official Pi OS image, or `/dev/mmcblk0p6` if you use NOOBS.